# CKAN: update metadata_created and metadata_modified infos

Tags: ckan

I have a testing empty CKAN portal and I'm creating dataset via API.

Now I would like to update metadata_created and metadata_modified values, but it seems impossible to do it via https://examplesite.com/api/3/action/package_update action.

Is there a way via API to update them?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

No, these values are currently overwritten in `package_dict_save()` and used by all API logic functions.

I don't think there's been a need for that yet, but you'd be welcome to [put it forward as an idea](https://github.com/ckan/ideas-and-roadmap/issues) and resource its implementation.

The idea is that these fields are automatically generated - a reflection of when the metadata is created and updated in CKAN. An exception I've been involved with is when harvesting metadata from another site - it seems reasonable to copy the original creation and update timestamps, and a harvester does have the access to change the values in the model. But via the API it's not been implemented.