# How to update CKAN metadata_created field for a dataset?

Tags: ckan

I would like to update the `metadata_created` field for a number of datasets (that were migrated from a previous system and so have incorrect creation times in CKAN).

I tried using the ckanapi to do this, but the field cannot be updated with the API, as previously noted here: [CKAN: update metadata_created and metadata_modified infos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58503506/ckan-update-metadata-created-and-metadata-modified-infos)

I then tried updating the `metadata_created` field in the `package` table directly via psql:

```
ckan=> select id, metadata_created, metadata_modified from package where id = 'a0f8e50d-aa28-4c5a-8aca-818d920244c9';
                  id                  |     metadata_created      |     metadata_modified
--------------------------------------+---------------------------+----------------------------
 a0f8e50d-aa28-4c5a-8aca-818d920244c9 | 2023-07-07 07:27:52.60954 | 2023-07-25 06:03:54.922081
(1 row)

ckan=> update package
set metadata_created = '1999-12-31T23:59:59'
where id = 'a0f8e50d-aa28-4c5a-8aca-818d920244c9';                                                                            UPDATE 1

ckan=> select id, metadata_created, metadata_modified from package where id = 'a0f8e50d-aa28-4c5a-8aca-818d920244c9';
                  id                  |  metadata_created   |     metadata_modified
--------------------------------------+---------------------+----------------------------
 a0f8e50d-aa28-4c5a-8aca-818d920244c9 | 1999-12-31 23:59:59 | 2023-07-25 06:03:54.922081
(1 row)
```

.. but this is not subsequently reflected by the API/UI:

```
$ ckanapi action package_show id=a0f8e50d-aa28-4c5a-8aca-818d920244c9 -r https://our.ckan.tld | jq  '.metadata_created'
"2023-07-07T07:27:52.609540"
```

Is there a cache that needs to be flushed/refreshed, in order for this update to become visible?

(Note that making a trivial change to some other field in the dataset - via the API - seems to make the update visible, but that's not a practical solution for the large number of records that we need to update).

Thanks.

Robert.

I updated the `package` table row with the required value of `metadata_created` and expected this to be reflected in the UI/API.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this turned out to be a rebuild of the Solr index, which we achieved by running this command from one of the CKAN containers:

```
ckan -c /path/to/ckan.ini search-index rebuild
```

After running the above, the metadata timestamps from the 'ckanapi' matched those in the postgres DB.